# Eclipse CompilationParticipant is not triggering

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, interactive

I am trying to develop a plugin which acts interactively with java source code. I declared the extension point org.eclipse.jdt.core.compilationParticipant.

`<extension
         point="org.eclipse.jdt.core.compilationParticipant">
      <compilationParticipant
            class="compilation.IDRCCompilationParticipant"
            createsProblems="false"
            id="IDRC.IDRCcompilationParticipant"
            modifiesEnvironment="false"
            requiredSourceLevel="1.5">
      </compilationParticipant>
   </extension>`

In my class IDRCcompilationParticipant, I am trying to print something whenever anything is changed in source code.

```
public class IDRCCompilationParticipant extends CompilationParticipant {

public IDRCCompilationParticipant() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
@Override
public void buildFinished(IJavaProject project) {
    // do nothing by default

    System.out.println("build finished");
}
public void reconcile(ReconcileContext context) {
    // do nothing by default
    System.out.println("reconcile");

         System.out.println("Content changed!");
}
}
```

While testing the plugin, I am expecting to print "Content changed!", whenever any method change etc happened in any source code in any java project. But nothing is triggering   `public void reconcile(ReconcileContext context)` method. Can anyone suggest what to do?

Comment: Not sure if Sysout works with eclipse-plugin. Try adding a some other logic / pop-up message there to verify.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer for it. Have to override two more methods from CompilationParticipant

```
    @Override
public int aboutToBuild(IJavaProject project) {

    return READY_FOR_BUILD;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.CompilationParticipant#isActive(org.eclipse.jdt.core.IJavaProject)
 */
@Override
public boolean isActive(IJavaProject project) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}
```

It works fine now.